# .Net Framework 3.5 not being installed on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net-3.5, dotnet-framework

Server : Windows Server 2008 (Standard) Service pack 2

All website running before on Framework 3.5 was stopped working and was giving error :

> Error Code : 0x80070032
>   Config Error : The configuration section 'appSettings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

So I tried to repair & re-install framework 3.5 but it was giving error while repairing or re-installing. Even it was not allow to uninstall it.
So uninstalled it by using Clean-up utility given on this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx
Now there is no framework 3.5 on server but it is not allowing to install it. Just gives message "`Setup Error`", no more detail and leaves success message in Event Viewer

> Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 -- Installation completed successfully.

Other message in event viewer is

> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. Product Version: 3.5.30729. Product Language: 0. Installation success or error status: 0.

Is there any solution to install it?

**Edit:**
there are couple of update installed showing in Windows update and there are two update available. but Windows is not able to install. and Windows not allowing to uninstall those installed update and gives message `the action is only valid for products that are currently installed`
In `C:\Windows\assembly` folder it still show .net 3.5 related entries (System.Core, System.Data.Linq etc.)

**Edit:**
log file `dd_clwireg.txt` content (it generates only this log file) :

```
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !Begin Microsoft .NET Framework Registration Correction Tool
[01/18/17,07:45:49] The following product GUIDs were specified on the commandline:
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {2FC099BD-AC9B-33EB-809C-D332E1B27C40}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {B6EC01E7-431D-4D29-B9D4-E1D74CAF0AB0}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {72EB0C4F-A51D-4203-B841-E529F6C4F571}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {7131646D-CD3C-40F4-97B9-CD9E4E6262EF}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {B508B3F1-A24A-32C0-B310-85786919EF28}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {340DFCEA-8855-4722-99B3-1BBAC5DDC088}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {0ADCF9F9-7EA9-48B5-9656-D65B2B246203}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {89BF6CBE-A47A-4CAB-AE77-D0D5A234CCA5}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {F7855754-13F5-426B-B090-5875FAFF1B20}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {2BA00471-0328-3743-93BD-FA813353A783}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {F1A37352-02A5-4F9A-A902-B9537DE1086F}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {2C8F9A07-43F7-4C31-9401-21B0CFAD94D3}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {9C93EC33-91B7-4900-8D88-15E5695440C9}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {15095BF3-A3D7-4DDF-B193-3A496881E003}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {491DD792-AD81-429C-9EB4-86DD3D22E333}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {7D1B85BD-AA07-48B8-808D-67A4067FC6BD}
[01/18/17,07:45:49]     {BAF78226-3200-4DB4-BE33-4D922A799840}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {2FC099BD-AC9B-33EB-809C-D332E1B27C40}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {2FC099BD-AC9B-33EB-809C-D332E1B27C40}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {2FC099BD-AC9B-33EB-809C-D332E1B27C40}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {B6EC01E7-431D-4D29-B9D4-E1D74CAF0AB0}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {B6EC01E7-431D-4D29-B9D4-E1D74CAF0AB0}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {B6EC01E7-431D-4D29-B9D4-E1D74CAF0AB0}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {72EB0C4F-A51D-4203-B841-E529F6C4F571}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {72EB0C4F-A51D-4203-B841-E529F6C4F571}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {72EB0C4F-A51D-4203-B841-E529F6C4F571}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {7131646D-CD3C-40F4-97B9-CD9E4E6262EF}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {7131646D-CD3C-40F4-97B9-CD9E4E6262EF}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {7131646D-CD3C-40F4-97B9-CD9E4E6262EF}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {B508B3F1-A24A-32C0-B310-85786919EF28}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {B508B3F1-A24A-32C0-B310-85786919EF28}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {B508B3F1-A24A-32C0-B310-85786919EF28}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {340DFCEA-8855-4722-99B3-1BBAC5DDC088}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {340DFCEA-8855-4722-99B3-1BBAC5DDC088}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {340DFCEA-8855-4722-99B3-1BBAC5DDC088}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {0ADCF9F9-7EA9-48B5-9656-D65B2B246203}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {0ADCF9F9-7EA9-48B5-9656-D65B2B246203}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {0ADCF9F9-7EA9-48B5-9656-D65B2B246203}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {89BF6CBE-A47A-4CAB-AE77-D0D5A234CCA5}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {89BF6CBE-A47A-4CAB-AE77-D0D5A234CCA5}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {89BF6CBE-A47A-4CAB-AE77-D0D5A234CCA5}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {F7855754-13F5-426B-B090-5875FAFF1B20}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {F7855754-13F5-426B-B090-5875FAFF1B20}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {F7855754-13F5-426B-B090-5875FAFF1B20}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {2BA00471-0328-3743-93BD-FA813353A783}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {2BA00471-0328-3743-93BD-FA813353A783}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {2BA00471-0328-3743-93BD-FA813353A783}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {F1A37352-02A5-4F9A-A902-B9537DE1086F}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {F1A37352-02A5-4F9A-A902-B9537DE1086F}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {F1A37352-02A5-4F9A-A902-B9537DE1086F}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {2C8F9A07-43F7-4C31-9401-21B0CFAD94D3}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {2C8F9A07-43F7-4C31-9401-21B0CFAD94D3}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {2C8F9A07-43F7-4C31-9401-21B0CFAD94D3}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {9C93EC33-91B7-4900-8D88-15E5695440C9}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {9C93EC33-91B7-4900-8D88-15E5695440C9}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {9C93EC33-91B7-4900-8D88-15E5695440C9}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {15095BF3-A3D7-4DDF-B193-3A496881E003}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {15095BF3-A3D7-4DDF-B193-3A496881E003}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {15095BF3-A3D7-4DDF-B193-3A496881E003}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {491DD792-AD81-429C-9EB4-86DD3D22E333}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {491DD792-AD81-429C-9EB4-86DD3D22E333}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {491DD792-AD81-429C-9EB4-86DD3D22E333}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {7D1B85BD-AA07-48B8-808D-67A4067FC6BD}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {7D1B85BD-AA07-48B8-808D-67A4067FC6BD}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {7D1B85BD-AA07-48B8-808D-67A4067FC6BD}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!Begin removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {BAF78226-3200-4DB4-BE33-4D922A799840}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] INFO: no patches were found under product {BAF78226-3200-4DB4-BE33-4D922A799840}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !!End removing or fixing missing patch registration for all patches under product {BAF78226-3200-4DB4-BE33-4D922A799840}
[01/18/17,07:45:49] DEBUG: Final error code 0 - returning zero.
[01/18/17,07:45:49] !End Microsoft .NET Framework Registration Correction Tool
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Comment: I tried repair tool many time, I ran "SFC /SCANNOW", tried Windows Update but no luck.

Comment: on thing I observed that there are couple of update installed showing in Windows update and there are two update available. but Windows is not able to install. and Windows not allowing to uninstall those installed update and gives message `the action is only valid for products that are currently installed`

Comment: Are you using standalone .NET Framework installer or Windows Add Features Wizard?

Comment: it's installer. Windows Add Features has only Framework 3.0 option.